# Filtering dropdownlist based on previous dropdownlist

Tags: html, filter, dropdown, disabled-input

I would like to ask how to filter the second dropdown list based on first dropdown list selected by user?

For example: If user select AIA in first dropdown list, the second dropdown list is disabled.

```
<tr>
    <td NOWRAP WIDTH="15%"><font FACE="ARIAL" SIZE="2"><strong>Level 1 Organizer</strong></font></td>
    <td NOWRAP >
            <font FACE="ARIAL" SIZE="2"><strong>
        <select name="Organizer" size="1" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt" onchange="Validate_Report_Level(this.value)">
            <option value="Partnership">Partnership</option>
            <option value="AIA">AIA</option>
            <option value="Agency">Agency</option>
        </select>
            </strong></font>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: @Suresh Kommuri  Could u help me to look into this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

html:

```
<select class="selectItem" name="Organizer" size="1" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt">
  <option value="Partnership">Partnership</option>
  <option value="AIA">AIA</option>
  <option value="Agency">Agency</option>
</select>

<select class="selectItem" name="Organizer" size="1" style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt">
  <option value="Partnership">Partnership</option>
  <option value="AIA">AIA</option>
  <option value="Agency">Agency</option>
</select>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.selectItem').on('change', function () {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  $('.selectItem option:not(.selected)').prop('disabled', false);
  $('.selectItem option[value="' + value + '"]:not(.selected)').prop('disabled', true);
  $(this).removeClass('selected');
});
```

check: https://jsfiddle.net/ws6xp69r/

Comment: Thank you and appreciate for your prompt reply. I did learn something from you:)